# How to add IF statements in CMD

Tags: command-line

With my .cmd script, all I am doing is creating a new file, setting a location for the file, naming it and adding an extension. I need one last bit to finish this.

If nothing is entered in fileLocation then I want it to be place on the desktop. How can I do this?

```
@echo off
@echo --- Create A New File ---
@echo -
@echo Choose File Desination.
set /p fileLocation=@
@echo -
@echo What do you want to call your new file?
set /p fileName=@
@echo -
@echo Almost Done! What is the files extension?
set /p extension=@
echo -
copy NUL "%fileLocation%/%fileName%.%extension%"
```

Comment: If you have `@echo off` you don't need to repeat the `@` each time.

Answer (score 2):

See [Microsoft DOS if command](http://www.computerhope.com/if.htm) or [this](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html).

To test for the existence of a parameter use empty brackets like this

```
IF [%fileLocation%]==[] ECHO Value Missing
```

Comment: I'm a noob at this, can you explain how to insert it in the command pleasse?

Comment: For the MS docs see here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754335(WS.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

IF [condition] [command]

```
  if %1==dhcp (
    netsh int ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
    netsh int ip set dns "Local Area Connection" dhcp
  ) else (
    netsh int ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static 192.168.%1.%2 255.255.255.0 192.168.%1.1 1
    netsh int ip set dns "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.%1.1
  )
```

This will taken the first and second parameters passed to the script file (`script.bat dhcp` or `script.bat 14 25`) and set the IP to either DHCP or 192.168.[14].[25] - %1 and %2 respectively

Note: I've never had good luck nesting IFs within a batch script, i usually will call another batch like a function if i need to do nesting, or use VBS.

Answer (score 0):

I would use double quotes and use the `%~1` (without double quotes):

```
if "%~1"=="value" (echo True) else (echo False)
```